# alsaequal: use command line to adjust sound

Tags: command-line, sound, alsa, raspberrypi, equalizer

I was looking into rotary encoders for adjusting the volume on my raspi. That part was quite easy. Now I am wondering, if it is possible to use the command line (and finally a rotary encoder) to adjust not only the volume, but the bars/elements in [alsaequal](https://github.com/raedwulf/alsaequal/blob/master/README)?

I have done some research, but - to my suprise - I could not find any information (so probably I don't know, what I should be looking for)

I really would appreciate any hint into the right direction :)

Comment: Did you read `man alsaequal`?

Comment: https://github.com/raedwulf/alsaequal/blob/master/README

Comment: thanks for the help. i have already read the github readme (now once again) ... maybe I just don't get it, but I found no information on how to adjust the frequency response by command line input (there is just the info how to open the equalizer with alsamixer -D equal). Am I missing something?

Comment: @waltinator: I read the github readme ... but I didn't find a more detailed manual. If I switch to the command line and write "man alsaequal" I get the info that no manual could be found ...

Answer (score 0):

the solution to my problem was the following command:
**sudo amixer -D equal '00. 31 Hz' 30%** which sets the frequency bar for 31 Hz to 30 %

Comment: Somehow this doesn't work for me: `amixer: Unknown command '00. 31 Hz'...`.

Comment: For me it was missing the `sset` command. This works for me now: 'amixer -D equal sset "00. 31 Hz" 30%'